# Generate Azure Databricks Token using Powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, databricks, azure-databricks

I need to generate Azure Databricks token using Powershell script.
I am done with creation of Azure Databricks using ARM template , now i am looking to generate Databricks token using powershell script .

Kindly let me know how to create Databricks token using Powershell script

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Still, I haven't tried much , I am looking of Powershell commands using which we can generate token but unable to find any.

Comment: It seems that you cloud use this [token API](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/api/latest/tokens.html).

Comment: I will be great , if you can provide some more info on how to use this token API in powershell , I also got the few references regarding the same , below is the url

https://github.com/gbrueckl/Databricks.API.PowerShell/blob/master/Modules/DatabricksPS/Public/TokensAPI.ps1

Answer (score 4):

The only way to generate a new token is via the api which requires you to have a token in the first place. 
Or use the Web ui manually. 
There is no official powershell commands for databricks, there are some unofficial ones but they still require you to generate a token manually first.

https://github.com/DataThirstLtd/azure.databricks.cicd.tools

Disclaimer I'm the author of these.

UPDATE: these powershell commands can now authenticate using a service principal instead of a bearer token (or can generate a bearer token for you).

Comment: can you please elaborate more on how these commands can generate a bearer token?

Comment: See this example: https://github.com/DataThirstLtd/databricks.vsts.tools/blob/master/deployCreateBearer/vstsDeployCreateBearer.ps1

Answer (score 0):

so right now there is no way to use the API directly after deploying an Azure Databricks Workspace. I assume that you want to use it as part of an CI/CD pipeline - right? Reason is that you first need to manually create an API token which you can then use for all subsequent API requests.
But I will investigate and keep you updated here!

Answer (score 0):

another option is to create it via terraform.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/token

mind you, it creates the token as whomever you az login'd as.  so if you az login as yourself (when it spawns a browser asking who to log in as), that's who the token will be created as (assuming that user has permissions in the databricks workspace) and contributor (or custom read role, reader role doesn't grant the right permissions) permissions into the resource group that houses the workspace.

you can always use az login -u username@email.com -p  to log in as someone else, assuming that user doesn't have MFA then run the terraform init/plan/apply.  mind you, if you have a backend storage, that user also has to have permissions to that backend storage as well so it can create/update any tfstate files stored there.