# Azure Databricks CI/CD - Octopus Question

Tags: octopus-deploy, azure-databricks, octopus

I am trying to automate the Azure Databricks service, cluster creation using Octopus releases. It looks like currently the Databricks access token need to be generated manually to make the rest of the REST Api calls - [Access Token Creation using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54122815/generate-azure-databricks-token-using-powershell-script).

Here are the steps I am trying to achieve.

1. Create the Azure Databricks Service
2. Manual Step to wait for the Access Token
3. Create the Clusters and Users on the Databricks.

On the second step how can I pass the manually generated token to a variable when the octopus release is in progress? I know Octopus supports the 'Prompted Variables' but I don't think it can be used while the release is in progress. Is there any work around I could use? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the resolution, Thanks to the Octopus Support team for providing the input.

The value entered by the user in the manual intervention step is available in PowerShell via $OctopusParameters["Octopus.Action[get token].Output.Manual.Notes"] where 'get token' is the name of the manual intervention step.