# How to create first Azure Databrics token programmatically (powershell)

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-databricks

We want to generate Azure databrics Access token using Powershell. From the docs, it says that we need a token first (created manually) then we can use the Token API to create the subsequent tokens.

In my situation, we will not have any "manually" created tokens, and we will have to create the first Access token programmatically. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/authentication#authentication to create token manually?

Comment: We are automating certain tasks on ADBs that will not have any tokens. So, the 'first' access token that we will have to create will be via a script.

Comment: If you want to use the [token API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/tokens) or other ways to generate token, we must create the first token manually. For more details, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54122815/generate-azure-databricks-token-using-powershell-script

Comment: Are there any other ways to authenticate to WorkSpace other than access tokens?

Comment: No, it is not possible as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot create Azure Databricks token programmatically.

You need to create Azure Databricks personal access token manually by going to the Azure Databricks portal.

Even for creating using APIs, initial authentication to this API is the same as for all of the Azure Databricks API endpoints: you must first authenticate as described in [Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/authentication#authentication).

Answer (score 1):

You can create an initial token using REST API but authenticating using the AAD Token as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/). Here is an example on how you can do it by acquiring AAD token via az-cli:

```sh
$ export DATABRICKS_TOKEN=$(az account get-access-token --resource=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d|jq -r .accessToken)
$ export DATABRICKS_HOST="https://adb-er2323423.9.azuredatabricks.net"
$ curl -s -n -X POST  "$DATABRICKS_HOST/api/2.0/token/create" \
  --data-raw '{"lifetime_seconds": 100,"comment": "this is an example token"}' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $DATABRICKS_TOKEN"
{"token_value":"aaaa",
"token_info":{ "token_id":"1312312312","creation_time":1624438106008,
  "expiry_time":1624438206008,"comment":"this is an example token"}}
```